# Can I use a CSS preprocessor with Polymer?

Tags: css, polymer, autoprefixer

With Polymer I can include my CSS styles in the element definition simply by adding a `<style>` tag. What I would like to do though is to add a preprocessor to those styles. Something like https://autoprefixer.github.io/ would be great.

Is there a way to do so without an external CSS file?

Answer (score 2):

Use a build step to extract inline resources to separate files - something like [gulp-html-extract](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-extract).

Once you have the source extracted, you can process it separately.

You would then use a tool like Vulcanize to re-inline your styles back into your main component.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I read through https://www.npmjs.com/package/crisper and didn't see anything about CSS. It appears to just be for JavaScript. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @nick Looks like you are correct. Process is the same though - you'll just need a different tool.